# IElement added to IGraphicsContainer ignores zOrder

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

I display a balloon callout after casting a axMapControl.Map to a IActiveView and doing this:

```
pGraphicsContainer = activeView as IGraphicsContainer;
pGraphicsContainer.AddElement(pElement, zOrder); 
pElement.Activate(activeView.ScreenDisplay);
```

The problem is the balloon callout displays below the place labels layer. The text "Minneapolis" is visible on top of my balloon callout.  I have tested zOrder with values from -10 to 10000 and the place labels still render on top of the balloon callout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [IGraphicsContainer.AddElement](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AddElement_Method/0012000005q8000000/) documentation:

> The parameter zorder is currently not utilized by all of the IGraphicsContainer implementations and is typically set to 0 when calling this method.

You can alter the element z-order using methods like [IGraphicsContainer.BringToFront](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/BringToFront_Method/0012000005qn000000/), SendToBack, BringForward and SendBackward. I suppose GetElementOrder and SetElementOrder also serve for this purpose, allowing you to set the z-order at once, but I've never tested.

Anyway, this affects only the z-order of graphic elements, not layer labeling, which is a separate process. Depending on the layer label weight settings, labels draw next to graphic elements (using a placement conflict resolution algorithm) or above them. I remember I was able to tweak this behaviour by creating a separate graphics layer under the map's [BasicGraphicsLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000m8t000000), adding graphic elements to it, and setting this graphic layer's [IBarrierProperties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IBarrierProperties_Interface/001200000233000000/).Weight accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Some example code would be exemplary. I can't find the SetElementOrder call and using BringForward hangs the application for some reason. So I would really appreciate an example from anyone.